# How do I create a for loop in masm only using jmp and eflags?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I tried googling everything about `jmp` statements and `eflags` but to no avail. This the only way I got it to work but I think I'm wrong.

```
.386         
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

;includelib msvcrt   ;printf function

Sleep proto arg1:DWORD  ;Sleep proto stdcall arg1:DWORD 

printf proto c arg1:Ptr BYTE, printlist:vararg 
scanf  PROTO c arg2:Ptr BYTE, inputlist:vararg

.data 

num db 1,2,3,4,0

fmtmsg1 db "%d",0   


.code
public main

main proc  

    mov cl,0 ; for loop counter 

repeat_loop:

    ;preserve for loop counter 
    push ecx

    ;move the contents of the pointer into the accumulator 
    mov al,[num]

    ;print the contents of the accumulator
    invoke printf,addr fmtmsg1,al

    ;increment the address pointed to by num pointer
    inc num

    ;retrive the counter value 
    pop ecx

    ;and increment the value
    inc cl

    ;compare the counter to 4 sets the z flag to 0 if not equal to 4
    cmp cl,4

    ;repeat loop
    jne repeat_loop

    ;if jump not taken the program returns to the operating system
     ret
main endp

end main
```

Comment: Why do you think you are wrong? That looks pretty much correct to me.

Comment: guess my question is why do i need to preserve the counter on the stack within the loop

Comment: Because the [C calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) that `printf` uses says `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` may be freely modified by functions. As such, you can't rely on their value being preserved across calls. You can of course use a preserved register such as `ebx`, but then you also have to preserve it for your caller which again boils down to storing it on the stack.

Comment: thank you i get it now but is there info out there that i can use to study why printf uses eax ecx and edx or guess im asking where did you get that info from is it trial and error or is there a manuel thet tells you this about certain functions

Comment: I [linked you to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). It's not per function. All functions in the C libraries use the C calling convention. On windows, the winapi functions use the stdcall convention (also described there). Of course there are more official documents.